# Access 2016 (64bit) MSO (365) deployed database cannot run with any runtime avaliable

Tags: ms-access, ms-office, ms-access-2016

I've made an application on an MS Access 2016 with 365 subscription and deployed an .accde file. When I try to open that file on another PC with runtime installed (tried with 2016 4288-1001 64bit and 2013 64bit) I get an error saying "Database you are trying to open requires a newer version of Microsoft Access".

I know that are some issues related to runtime and 365, but some people said that using runtime 2013 solved their problem (but not mine).

Anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: Found the problem. Some of my table fields data was set as "Big Numbers". I don't know why, but Access Runtime 2016 can't read this data type, changing this made the file open.

Comment: Suggestion: add the exact error message to your question and self-answer it with the solution so others can find it

Comment: Thank you for your sugestion. Just did the changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that some of my table fields data was set as "Large Number". 
I don't know why, but Access Runtime 2016 can't read this data type, changing the fields to "Number" made the deployed ".accde" open normally.

Source: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3208802/-database-you-are-trying-to-open-requires-a-newer-version-of-microsoft